# A micro instance recreating itself automatically

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I created a micro instance (Ubuntu) on Amazon EC2. Then, I created image from the instance (I want to backup my installed environment).

Later, I decided to delete the instance and created new instance with the image. After I did that, there were two new micro instances created instead of one instance.

I had no idea where the other instance came from. And when I delete the automatically created instance, it always recreates. I just want to use ONE micro instance (Free Tier).

Does anybody know how to solve this issue?

Comment: Isn't there a property "Protect against accidental termination"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your Auto Scaling settings. If you've configured a minimum of 1 instance, it will always relaunch a new one to maintain that minimum bar.